# How to verify a method inside a method is called in mockito

Tags: flutter, dart, mockito

I was doing some unit testing in flutter with mockito, and I feels unable to verify a method is called within another method. The code I've written so far as follows,

The class I want to test

```
class A {
  void doSomething() {
    callMe();
  }

  void callMe() {}
}
```

Mocked class

```
class MockA extends Mock implements A {}
```

The test I wrote,

```
test("Test method is called", () {
    A a = new MockA();
    a.doSomething();
    verify(a.callMe()).called(1);
  });
```

When I run the above test I am getting an error

```
No matching calls. All calls: MockA.doSomething()
(If you called `verify(...).called(0);`, please instead use `verifyNever(...);`.)
```

If i verify doSomething is called it works, but for a call on callMe within doSomething doesn't work. Is this the default behavior or am I doing something wrong? Please note I need to verify the callMe() method is called when doSomething() is called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mocked `A` and replaced it with `MockA`. Mocks have no implementation. `MockA.doSomething()` *does nothing* and does not and cannot call `MockA.callMe()`.

That `A.doSomething()` calls `A.callMe()` should be considered an implementation detail of `doSomething()`; making a test rely on that would tightly couple the test to the specific implementation and would be brittle.

You can't use a mock to verify the implementation of the thing being mocked.  If you want to verify the implementation of `A.doSomething()`, you instead should use an actual (not mocked) instance of `A` and then verify observable properties on that instance.

But if you still really want to do this, then you would need to modify `A` to not call methods on itself and to instead call methods on a provided object (i.e., "dependency injection").  For example:

```dart
class A {
  final late A a;

  A({A? a}) {
    this.a = a ?? this;
  }

  void doSomething() {
    a.callMe();
  }

  void callMe() {}
}

test("Test method is called", () {
    var mockA = MockA();
    var actualA = A(a: mockA);
    actualA.doSomething();
    verify(mockA.callMe()).called(1);
  });
```

It's a bit unusual for a class to depend on a mock of itself, however, and it would not scale if you then want to verify calls made by `callMe()`.

Another approach that would scale better (but with significantly more work) would be to create your own fake class that tracks method calls:

```dart
class TrackedA implements A {
  int doSomethingCallCount = 0;
  int callMeCallCount = 0;

  @override
  void doSomething() {
    doSomethingCallCount += 1;
    super.doSomething();
  }

  @override
  void callMe() {
    callMeCallCount += 1;
    super.callMe();
  }
}
```

But again, that's very brittle, and I would not recommend it.

Comment: Thanks for the descriptive answer. Now I got an understanding.