type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<UserPermissionApiResponse>' while writing unit test case in dart using mocktail
I am trying to write the unit test case for a method called authenticate which has nested method of the same class called login. Now I want to mock the login method and run the test case. I did that but somehow I am getting the above error.
Here is the method:
Future<UserPermissionApiResponse> authenticate(
      String userId, String password, BuildContext context, Util util) async {
    if (userId.isNotEmpty && password.isNotEmpty) {

     
      String deviceId = await util.getDeviceId();

      /// Calling login API
      UserPermissionApiResponse userPermissionApiResponse = await logIn(
          context: context,
          credentials: password,
          deviceId: deviceId,
          userId: userId);

      return userPermissionApiResponse;
    } else {
      return UserPermissionApiResponse(result: false, message: constants.invalidCredentialsErrorMsg);
    }

Here is the test case for the above method:
test('authenticate method - valid userId and password', () async {
      // Arrange
      when(() => util.getDeviceId())
          .thenAnswer((_) => Future.value('deviceId'));

      when(() => loginRepository.logIn(
            context: context,
            credentials: 'password',
            deviceId: 'deviceId',
            userId: 'userId',
          )).thenAnswer((_) => Future.value(UserPermissionApiResponse(
            result: true,
            message: 'Login successful',
          )));

      // Act
      final response = await loginRepository.authenticate(
        'userId',
        'password',
        context,
        util,
      );

      // Assert
      expect(response.result, true);
      expect(response.message, 'Login successful');
    });

Here is the complete test class:
class MockBuildContext extends Mock implements BuildContext {}

class MockUtil extends Mock implements Util {}

class MockLoginRepositoryImpl extends Mock implements LoginRepositoryImpl {}

void main() {
  TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  late LoginRepositoryImpl loginRepository;
  late BuildContext context;
  late Util util;

  setUp(() {
    loginRepository = MockLoginRepositoryImpl();
    context = MockBuildContext();
    util = MockUtil();
  });

  group('authenticate', () {
    test('authenticate method - valid userId and password', () async {
      // Arrange
      when(() => util.getDeviceId())
          .thenAnswer((_) => Future.value('deviceId'));

      when(() => loginRepository.logIn(
            context: context,
            credentials: 'password',
            deviceId: 'deviceId',
            userId: 'userId',
          )).thenAnswer((_) => Future.value(UserPermissionApiResponse(
            result: true,
            message: 'Login successful',
          )));

      // Act
      final response = await loginRepository.authenticate(
        'userId',
        'password',
        context,
        util,
      );

      // Assert
      expect(response.result, true);
      expect(response.message, 'Login successful');
    });
  });
}

I tried mocking the login method but still getting the same issue.

Could you edit your post and include the error message with the stack trace. I will make it easier to see what is going on.

As mentioned by the Mocktail documentation, "type 'Null' is not a subtype of type ..." indicates that you're missing a stub.  You're calling loginRepository.authenticate where loginRepository is a MockLoginRepositoryImpl, but you haven't created a stub for it.  Your test makes no sense; you cannot test the implementation/behavior of loginRepository.authenticate on a Mock object because a Mock has no implementation.

If you want to test your implementation of the authenticate method, you must call it on a real object with your actual implementation.  You might be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/73240877/ (adapting it to use Mocktail instead of Mockito).
